# How to disable button in android?

Tags: android

I have a login page,having 2 textfields username,password and button "login" button.
when the username or password not entered alert is poping up, 
when i suddenly clicks on this login button 2 alerts are poping up, 
since more than click is taken.
I need to disable the button and enable during next click. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

in order to disable a button, you have to call

```
yourButton.setEnabled(false)
```

on a Button instance. To re enable it  call:

```
yourButton.setEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

create a method as below

```
    boolean checkit= true;
private void showHide1() {

    if (checkit) {

    // first click
    } else {
    // second click
    }
    checkit= !checkit;
}
```

and on you button click add the method showHide1();

Answer (score 0):

You can combine blackbelt's solution with mine.

Add a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to your `EditText` and **enable** or **disable** the button when text is entered in the `EditText`.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    charCount = Integer.valueOf(s.length());

    if (charCount > 0)  {           
        // ENABLE THE BUTTON
        boolean blnButtonStatus = YOUR_BUTTON.isEnabled();
        if (blnButtonStatus== false)    {
            YOUR_BUTTON.setEnabled(true);
        }

    } else if (charCount == 0)  {
        // DISABLE THE BUTTON
        YOUR_BUTTON.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // DO NOTHING HERE
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // DO NOTHING HERE
}
```

This way, the code will automatically disable the Button if there is nothing typed in the *Password* and /or *Username* fields. No accidental clicks.